# Are there any languages where "A == B == C" works where A, B, and C are all non-boolean types?

Tags: language-agnostic, type-conversion

Without thinking in C# I tried to compare three objects. It failed, and explained why [since (typeof("A == B") == bool) and (typeof(C) != bool) it was an invalid comparison]. Do any languages support short circuiting logic like this?

Comment: this is definitely a curiosity question. I will not be rewriting my program in other languages just so I don't have to type If( A == B && B == C). :)

Comment: @cheniel In this instance I was comparing int values, so A == B && B == C would imply that, although I suppose for types with complex equality tests A == C would probably be a good thing to test for.

Comment: Python: `A = 1; B = [1, 2, 3]; C = True; print A and B and C`. `True`. Meant this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several languages that let you do multiple conditionals like this.
But the first I could think of was Python

Example:

```
a = 5
b = 5
c = 5
if(a == b == c):
    print "yes"
else:
    print "no"
```

Will print "yes" in the console.

It works with other types as well, like this:

```
a = ["A",1]
b = ["A",1]
c = ["A",1]
d = ["A",1]
if(a == b == c == d):
    print "YES"
else:
    print "NO"
```

Now the reason for C# (And other C like languages) doesn't support this is that they evaluate comparison expressions down to a true / false, so what your compiler sees when you do (5 == 5 == 5) is ((5 == 5) == 5) which yields: (true == 5) which invalid since you cannot compare a Boolean to an integer, you could actually write (a == b == c) if c is a Boolean, so (5 == 5 == true) would work.